# Rails 4.1 upgrade resulting in missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I use rails with rabl, in 4.0.x it worked perfectly to render the correct result in a rabl template and errors just through render :json => {:error => 'oh no!'}.

I used

```
ActionController::Metal and 
  include ActionController::ForceSSL
  include ActionController::Redirecting
  include ActionController::Rendering
  include ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection
  include ActionController::Renderers::All
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender
  include AbstractController::Callbacks
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
  include ActionController::StrongParameters
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  append_view_path "#{Rails.root}/app/views"
```

With the upgrade to 4.1 I had to change ActionController::Rendering to AbstractController::Rendering and include ActionView::Layouts.

The problem: Without ActionView::Layouts I can render :json => {something} but my templates are not loaded. With ActionView::Layouts I get on every render :json => {...} a Missing Template error.

Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: I don't know enough about rabl, but just a though, have you also made sure to also upgrade the rabl gem to the latest, or at least the one stated to be compatible with Rails 4.1?

Comment: When I inherit my controller from ActionController::Base both cases work properly. I don't think the problem is related to the rabl gem, but my includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I figured it out. It was the order of my includes and instead of replacing ActionController::Rendering with AbstractController::Rendering I should have added it.

working ordering and list:

```
include AbstractController::Rendering
include ActionController::Redirecting
include ActionView::Layouts
include ActionController::Rendering
include ActionController::Renderers::All
include ActionController::MimeResponds
include ActionController::ImplicitRender
include ActionController::StrongParameters
include ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection
include ActionController::ForceSSL
include AbstractController::Callbacks
include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
```